# Number of occurrences of words in a file - Complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashtable

Given I have a file which a set of words:

1) If I choose a hash table to store word -> count, what would be the time complexity to find the occurrences of a particular word?

2) How could I return those words alphabetically ordered?

If I chose a hash table, I know that the time complexity for 1) would be O(n) to parse all the words and O(1) to get the count of a particular word.

I fail to see how could I order the hash table and what would be the time complexity. Any help?

Comment: Are you asking in a theoretical mindset? some map implementations offer ordering on the keys.

Comment: @UmNyobe Not map, hash. Hashing, by general consensus, doesn't maintain order.

Comment: Time complexity is an algorithm question and is answered below (usually O(n log n)), but how to order a hash table depends on the implementation, ie the language.

Answer (score 2):

A sortable hash map becomes, essentially, a binary tree. In java you can see TreeMap implementing the SortableMap interface with the O(log n) on look-up and insert.

If you want the best theoretical performance you'd use a HashMap with O(1) look-up and insert and then you'd use a bucket/radix sort with O(n) for display/iteration.

In reality using a radix sort on strings will perform worse than a quick sort O(n log n).

Comment: I just wonder why using a radix sort on strings will perform worse than a quick sort in reality. Any reason leading to that? Or just an evidence from experimental results?

Comment: Note - sortable map != sortable hash map. If you were not to define your hash function in such a way to force ordering (which is far from trivial to do, especially if you want to have a well-distributed function), a TreeMap with hashes as keys doesn't really help. And to have it sorted in the hash array (which is implicitly done) is probably more efficient.

Comment: @Terry Li - In this specific case where the strings are words, and there's a limited number of unique words/page, a straight radix sort may actually work the fastest. But in the general case, sorting strings with straight radix sort is impractical. Radix sort is KN where K is the maximum string length, if K is larger than log N for quick sort then from a pragmatic stance it's less efficient. Some modern research shows that sorting strings with a mix of radix and quick sort is superior.

Comment: @LastCoder +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: @Terry Li - Searching for (3 way radix quicksort, strings) turns up a lot of great information http://www.drdobbs.com/database/sorting-strings-with-three-way-radix-qui/184410724

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis of (1) is correct.

Most hash table implementations (that I know of) has no implicit ordering.

To get an ordered list you'd have to sort the list (`O(n log n)`), queries on the list would take `O(log n)`.

You could theoretically define a hash operation and implementation that sorts, but making it well-distributed (for it to be efficient) would be difficult and just sorting would be a lot simpler.

If it's a file containing lots of duplicates, the best idea may be to use hashing first to eliminate duplicates, then iterate through the hash table to get a list of non-duplicates and sort that.

Answer (score 0):

Working with hash tables has two drawbacks 1- They do not store data in sorted way, 2-Calculation of the hash value is usually time consuming. They also have linear complexity for insert/delete/lookup in the worst case.

My suggestion is using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for storing your words. Which has a guaranteed O(1) (number of words) for insert/lookup. A pre-order traverse over a Trie will give a sorted list of the words in the Trie.